# ASIO IO completion callbacks order vs the order of actual IO operations

Tags: c++, boost-asio

It is obvious from the implementation that IO completion callbacks are invoked in the same order as the actual IO operations when running in a single thread mode, but I cannot find the respective part of the documentation confirming that. Is it written explicitly anywhere?

Comment: someone's on a downvoting spree today?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of all of the async_xxx methods on io-object classes have a passage like this:

> Regardless of whether the asynchronous operation completes immediately or not, the handler will not be invoked from within this function. Invocation of the handler will be performed in a **manner equivalent to using** `boost::asio::io_service::post()`.

Looking at the documentation of `boost::asio::io_service::post()`...

> This function is used to ask the io_service to execute the given handler, but without allowing the io_service to call the handler from inside this function.
>
> The io_service guarantees that the handler will only be called in a thread in which the `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()` or `poll_one()` member functions is currently being invoked.

And that is the full extent of your guarantee.

If your code relies on the temporal ordering of asynchronous events, then it is not asynchronous code.

Even the documentation of `run_one()` make no guarantees about *which* handler it will dispatch:

> The run_one() function blocks until one handler has been dispatched, or until the io_service has been stopped.

If you must sequence individual async operations (such as reads), then you are obliged to either:

- initiate the second operation from the handler of the first, or
- keep a flag set while an operations' handler is outstanding, and only initiate another operation when the flag is false.

Comment: One of apps I work with is ignoring incoming protocol heartbeat requests (TCP-based protocol) if an async_write is in progress (remote end accepts any message as a heartbeat response). This nice shortcut works only if the (valid) assumption about ASIO  not reordering the completion callbacks between different epoll iterations holds. Thus the question, more from theoretical domain, where the logic is relying on documented or undocumented ASIO behavior.

Comment: @bobah The logic is relying on undocumented Asio behavior.  If the shortcut is indeed helpful, then it may be worth considering explicitly programming the logic with reactor-style operations.

Comment: @bobah I don't know... its your code. But if it were me I would prefer to have implicit sequencing of operations expressed explicitly.